# Hero Image Not Appering In ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have been researching this issue for days, and I still cant figure it out. I am aware this may be marked as a duplicate, because it is somewhat similar to some other posts; which I have looked at and they still have not answered my question.

I have been experimenting with ASP.NET MVC applications recently, and I was trying to add a hero image to the top of my site. I did this successfully in Dreamweaver (which I use to design the website before I insert it into VS.), but when I copied it into Visual Studio (2017 if that helps); it has merged my text into my banner, without even displaying the image.

How do I fix this? I have searched everywhere and can't find it.

(My Code Below)

```
    @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .hero-image {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url(images/background.png.png);
            background-size: contain;
        }

        .hero-text {
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            color: white;
        }

            .hero-text button {
                border: none;
                outline: 0;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 10px 25px;
                color: black;
                background-color: #ddd;
                text-align: center;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

                .hero-text button:hover {
                    background-color: #555;
                    color: white;
                }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="hero-image">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1 style="font-size:50px">TITLE</h1>
            <p>SUB TITLE</p>
            <button>BUTTON</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>Page Content..</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what it should look like:

[Image in Dreamweaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f2zw.png)

And this is what it does look like in ASP.NET:

[In ASP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Mft.png)

Here is my _Layout file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Code Club</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("title", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Challenges", "Challenges", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Resources", "Resources", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - KHC Code Club Group</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbZXv.png)

Folder structure is:

This PC > SolutionName > SolutionNAme > Views > Home. Banner is the file I am dealing with. Banner also contains the CSS, and the images folder contains the background.

Comment: Expected view and current view?

Comment: Expected View And Current View Added.

Comment: Check the Image path! -> *background-image: url(images/background.png.png);*?

Comment: The image path is correct. I have checked this. The image has double pngs because the site that I downloaded it from had it with double pngs. I have not been bothered to change it.

Comment: Have you checked after removing that @Layout?

Comment: I just did. It still produces the same result.

Comment: Just use this -> *background-image: url(../images/background.png.png);*  instead background-image: url(images/background.png.png);

Comment: As I checked on my local its working fine!

Comment: error in the console?

Comment: What is your folder structure? That means, can you post the snap here! with _layout.chtml page bcs those thing I dont know so I can copy the your code and try in my local

Comment: If you post your layout and folder structure in the question then will definitely help!

Comment: Folder Structure and _layout.cshtml added

Comment: is this what you required? --> [sample](https://imgur.com/Qo4s37f)

Comment: Please check above demo in which I have added background image, is that your expected output?

Comment: This is what I need: https://imgur.com/zmg36qA

Comment: If it is any help, This was created with authentication (Individual User Accounts)

Comment: the issue is with your *<div class="hero-image" style="height:700px; width:1000px">* div if you use height and width as I did above then it will display the image!

Comment: I'm afraid even that didn't work. It enlarged the page to the size of the image (made space for where the image would have been), but still isn't displaying it. I even tried different browsers (Instead of FireFox, I tried chrome, edge and explorer. None of them worked)

Comment: use this to display image --> *background-image: url(../views/Home/background.png.png);*

Comment: Somehow even that doesn't work. Not sure if it is just a bug with ASP.NEt or what...

Comment: You have to analyze your problem by step by step..and its not a bug just you are missing something i ma damn sure that its related to parent layout of your page